# SQS batching for Lambda trigger doesn't work as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have 2 Lambda Functions and an SQS queue inbetween.
The first Lambda sends the messages to the Queue.
Then second Lambda has a trigger for this Queue with a batch size of 250 and a batch window of 65 seconds.

I expect the second Lambda to be triggered in batches of 250 messages after about every 65 seconds. In the second Lambda I'm calling a 3rd party API that is limited to 250 API calls per minute (I get 250 tokens per minute).

I tested this setup with for 32.000 messages being added to the queue and the second Lambda didn't pick up the messages in batches as expected. At first it got executed for 15k messages and then there were not enough tokens so it did not process those messages.

The 3rd party API is based on a token bucket with a fill rate of 250 per minute and a maximum capacity of 15.000. It managed to process the first 15.000 messages due to the bucket capacity and then didn't have enough capacity to handle the rest.

I don't understand what went wrong.

[image]

Comment: Do I understand this correctly that after you added 32k messages to the SQS queue, your Lambda function got executed with 15k messages (in one batch?) instead of 250? And what is the _total bucket capacity_? Is it per hour or the number of total tokens that you can ever use?

Comment: To clarify: the 15k messages haven't been processed in a single Lambda invocation, right? It should have been about 60 and according to the docs the maximum batch size for standard SQS is 10k.

Comment: Have you checked your `Concurrent executions` and `Invocations` metrics for your lambda?

Comment: @Marcin The invokations are `41` and concurrent executions are `143`.

Comment: Yes, so this I think confirms @Maurice answer. Your functions run in parallel, not sequentially.

Comment: Thanks Maurice. I have another doubt, I've added the dlq from asynchronous invokation tab and have configured the dlq after retry of 1. These messages which were not processed should be in the dlq right? But I see no messages there.

Comment: If I recall correctly SQS is actually a synchronous invocation, because Lambda needs to delete the messages from the Queue afterwards, so the DLQ for asynchronous invocations shouldn't be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misunderstanding is probably related to how Lambda handles scaling.
Whenever there are more events than a single Lambda execution context/instance can handle, Lambda just creates more execution contexts/instances to process these events.

What probably happened is that Lambda saw there are a bunch of messages in the queue and it tries to work on these as fast as possible. It created a Lambda instance to handle the first event and then talked to SQS and asked for more work. When it got the next batch of messages, the first instance was still busy, so it scaled out and created a second one that worked on the second batch **in parallel**, etc. etc.

That's how you ended up going through your token budget in a few minutes.

You can limit how many functions Lambda is allowed to execute in parallel by using reserved concurrency - here are the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) for reference. If you set the reserved concurrency to 1, there will be no parallelization and only one Lambda is allowed to work on the messages.

This however opens you up to **another issue**. If that single Lambda takes less than 60 seconds to process the messages, Lambda will call it again with another batch ASAP and you might go over your budget again.

At this point a relatively simple approach would be to make sure that your lambda function always takes about 60 seconds by adding a sleep for the remaining time at the end.

Comment: Hi. Just wonder if there is anything better then sleep for 60 seconds? You will end-up paying for this idle time. Maybe there is a way to avoid it?

Comment: "If that single Lambda takes less than 60 seconds to process the messages, Lambda will call it again with another batch ASAP and you might go over your budget again.", but since I have defined batch window so shouldn't it pick next batch after 60 seconds, even if it has processed the previous batch in less than 60 seconds?

Comment: @Marcin - I thought about it, but couldn't come up with a much better solution. If there is consistent load on the queue it will definitely be cheaper to run a fargate container than the lambda. If there's sporadic load this may still be more cost effective.

Comment: @nats That's not how this works. It waits either for the configured 65 seconds or until 250 messages are available, whichever happens first. If there are more than 250 messages waiting in the queue there's no guarantee that it will only invoke every 60 seconds.

Comment: Oh okay! So it means that whichever condition becomes true it will get invoked again.

Comment: What if I calculate how much time 1 single lambda(with reserved concurrency 1)  takes to process the 250 messages and keep the lambda timeout same?

Comment: I don't see how that helps, the Lambda timeout isn't the bottleneck, the 3rd party API is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229287/discussion-between-nats-and-maurice).